# How to avoid space after bash variable in string?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution

I have a variable for color. I use it to set color to strings, by evaluating it inside the string. However, I need to include space after the name(so that the name doesn't contain part of the text). This sometimes looks bad.

How can I avoid using(printing) this space?

Example(Let's say that `Red=1` and `NC=2`):

```
echo -e "$Red Note: blabla$NC".
```

Output:

```
1 Note: blabla2.
```

Expected output:

```
1Note: blabla2.
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just enclose variable in braces:

```
echo -e "${Red}Note: blabla${NC}".
```

See more detail about [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

See also great answer [Why printf is better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/38906) if you care about portability.

Answer (score 7):

What you should get into the habit of using is printf:

```
printf '%sNote: blabla%s\n' "$Red" "$NC"
```

Where each `%s` replace a variable. And the `-e` is not needed as printf accepts backslash values \n,\t, etc in a portable manner.

Remember that `echo -e` is not portable to other shells.

#### Other options:

You could use two commands that concatenate their output:

```
echo -ne "$Red"; echo -e "Note: blabla$NC"
```

You could use simple string concatenation:

```
echo -e "$Red""Note: blabla$NC"
```

Or you could make use of `{ }` to avoid name-text confusions:

```
echo -e "${Red}Note: blabla$NC"
```